# Can’t Enable Raspberry Pi camera rev1.3

Tags: camera, raspi-config, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I have raspberry pi 4 model B and when I am trying to connect camera rev1.3 but I can’t find the camera in `raspi-config`, so I can't enable it.
I am using OS 32-bit bookworm.

Comment: In bookworm cameras are by default automatically detected and the option is not available in raspi-config. Also be aware that you need to use the new libcamera stack. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html